# IPv4 Addresses: Int or String as Data Type in AVRO schema

Tags: avro

I have the option of storing the IPv4 addresses either as an `int` or `string` while defining my avro schema. A `string` representation will make easier for the business application to understand natively.

However, an `int` representation can be efficiently contained within 4 bytes and also supports faster data comparison. Am I over-optimizing or violating schema principles in this case?

Comment: `Am I over-optimizing`: no, you are optimizing... 10us ? If you don't work on arduino or others embedded systems you don't need to economize 12 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Both are reasonable options.

Alternatively, you could use [logical types](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Logical+Types) to hide the underlying representation from clients. You could then expose addresses via a custom `IPv4` class (providing for example both integer and string representations, and maybe doing some validation).